# How to change websocket url in graphql-playground (subscriptions)

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I wanted to change the graphql websocket end point inside graphql, anyone know how to do this?

by default it pings

```
wss://localhost/graphql
```

I need to change it to pusher url

thanks :-)

Comment: Are you using `apollo-server-express`? Can you provide more information in how are you implementing the server?

Answer (score 8):

If you are running a standalone instance of GraphQL Playground, the URL is passed directly to the component as a prop:

```
<Playground
  endpoint="http://localhost/graphql"
  subscriptionEndpoint="wss://localhost/graphql"
/>
```

If you're using `apollo-server`, the endpoint URL should be derived from the `subscriptionsPath`, but it can also be set directly in the config:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    subscriptionEndpoint: 'wss://localhost/graphql',
  },
});
```

EDIT:

It doesn't appear there's a way to configure the desktop client with a specific subscription URL, unless you're using it with a local repo that contains a `.graphqlconfig`. In that case, you can provide additional information about your environment, including the subscription url, in the config file as outlined [here](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-config).

Comment: In graphql-playground (desktop client)